# https static content on NGINX

Tags: nginx, vps

I've inherited a configuration from a colleague for a VPS where NGINX has been setup. I can currently serve dynamic content via http and https, however static content like images, javascript and css are not loaded (shown as 404) when https is specified as the connection type.

As I've inherited the config, I'm not too sure where to start although I have unsuccessfully tried NGINX's own guide on adding a location block to the nginx.conf under http directive, specifying a root to use.

```
http{
  include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type  application/octet-stream;
  server_tokens off;
  ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    location / {
      root /var/www/;
    }
}
```

I do also get the same behaviour with NGINX disabled, however I'm unable to find any documentation in my colleagues notes on what else could be serving content.

Any pointers in the right direction would be much appreciated!

nginx.conf

```
user              nginx;
worker_processes  1;
error_log         /var/log/nginx/error.log;
pid               /var/run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}



http {

    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    server_tokens off;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;

    log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request "'
                      '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
                      '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
    access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    autoindex off;
    map $scheme $fastcgi_https { ## Detect when HTTPS is used
        default off;
        https on;
    }


client_header_timeout 3000;
client_body_timeout 3000;
fastcgi_read_timeout 3000;
client_max_body_size 32m;
fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;
fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;

    keepalive_timeout  10;

gzip  on;
gzip_http_version 1.1;
gzip_vary on;
gzip_comp_level 6;
gzip_proxied any;
gzip_types text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript application/javascript text/x-js;
gzip_buffers 16 8k;
gzip_disable "MSIE [1-6]\.(?!.*SV1)";
    # Load config files from the /etc/nginx/conf.d directory
    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;

}
```

Comment: `location` in `http` is invalid. Show your server config

Comment: I've added nginx.conf to the original post

Comment: I don't see any `server` block. They should be in `/etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;` files

Comment: I've since found that the reason I'm getting the 404's is that a string value of "internal-nginx-static-location" is being added to the requests, but I'm unable to see where it's being defined.

Answer (score 0):

Trawling through this I found that NGINX has been adding a command into the server >> Location blocks of x-accel-internal.

By copying the template proxy.php from conf/templates/default/domain/service into custom/domain/service and commenting out this command, nginx is serving content correctly again after re-creating the config files via SSH

```
/usr/local/psa/admin/bin/httpdmng --reconfigure-all
nginx -t && service nginx reload
```